# How to add html format on a vaadin label?

Tags: html, string, text, label, vaadin

I want to add an html formatted string on a vaadin label. The string comes from a database and goes straight to the label, it must be formatted with bold text, line breaks and some other fancy text things. I found a couple of solutions but those were for old version of vaadin, is there any way of doing this on vaadin flow?

Comment: Whatever you do, please remember to take care of output sanitization to reduce the risk of XSS vulnerabilities. When using Vaadin, you have JSoup on the classpath so you can use the `Jsoup.clean` method for doing that.

Comment: The HTML string comes from my database, added by me... I won't let users add custom text in a HTML format yet, so I guess there aren't vulnerabilities at the moment? But I definitely should add that when I accept custom HTML inputs, right?

Comment: Exactly. The challenge is to remember adding the sanitization later on if you give potentially untrusted users the permissions to submit contents to that part of the database. For that reason, I usually recommend doing it right away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add an HTML content to a label using:

```java
        Label label = new Label();
        label.getElement().setProperty("innerHTML","A new line should be created after this <br /> <b>This text is bold</b> <br /> <i> This text is italic</i>");
        add(label);
```

---

**BUT**, if you want to display only text, then the label is not a correct element to use. As stated in its [API](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.28/com/vaadin/flow/component/html/Label.html) :

> Note that Label components are not meant for loose text in the page - they should be coupled with another component by using the setFor(Component) or by adding them to it with the HasComponents.add(Component...) method.

I would use the `HTML` element instead :

```java
        String yourContent ="A new line should be created after this <br /> <b>This text is bold</b> <br /> <i> This text is italic</i>";
        Html html = new Html("<text>" + yourContent + "</text>");
        add(html);
```

The output :

[image]

Or you could encapsulate the functionality and create a general component for displaying an HTML snippets based using an example here : https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17072019

Comment: Thanks man! Using the HTML element is exactly what I was looking for, cheers!