# Pretty html formatted string on a vaadin Label

Tags: vaadin

how can I to add an html formatted string on a vaadin label so that it looks pretty?

It must be formatted with bold text, italic text, new lines, html things basically.

I'm using Vaadin 14. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add html format on a vaadin label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61860660/how-to-add-html-format-on-a-vaadin-label)

Comment: I already have my answer, thank you everyone, I love this site, it's very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this:

```
Label label = new Label();
label.getElement().setProperty("innerHTML","Just a sentence before a line break <br /> <b> bold text</b> <br /> <i> italic text</i>");
```

Or this:

```
String yourContent = "Just a sentence before a line break <br /> <b> bold text</b> <br /> <i> italic text</i>";
Html html = new Html("<text>" + yourContent + "</text>");
```

Comment: If the label is not used [in association with a form control](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/labels/#:~:text=Provide%20labels%20to%20identify%20all,purpose%20of%20the%20form%20control.) (i.e. to describe an input field), you should really use the `Html` component of Vaadin instead.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use `new Html("");`

`Label` corresponds to `<label>` and should only be used to label input fields.